# Map is not showing up in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get google maps to work in my project ,but for some reason nothing shows up on the page when I try to search localhost/front to access that page .

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laramap</title>
    </meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/main.css')}}">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </link>


</head>
<body>

@yield('content')
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4NNeHbNb1_nFhKnckNxMKpxXeQUecenM"
        async defer></script>

<script src="={{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

front.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')


  <div class="container">

      <div id="map">
      </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 8
    });

});
```

main.css

```
#map{

    heoght: 500px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::any('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['as' => 'user.'],function () {

    Route::get('/front',function () { return view('front');});
    Route::get('/settings',['as'=> 'settings','uses'=> 'ProfileController@viewSettings']);
    Route::post('/settings',['as'=> 'settings','uses'=> 'ProfileController@saveSettings']);
    Route::any('/profile/{userId}',['as'=> 'profile','uses'=> 'ProfileController@viewProfile']);

});
```

[image]

Comment: Change `heoght: 500px;` to `height:500px`

Comment: Still I don't get anything back

Comment: Did you get any Javascript Error? in console?

Comment: I didn't get any error ,I just keep on getting a blank page every time I try to access the page

Comment: If the entire page is blank, chances are an error message is sitting in `storage/logs/laravel.log` or your webserver's logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `&libraries=places` at the end of the key

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=AIzaSyC4NNeHbNb1_nFhKnckNxMKpxXeQUecenM&libraries=places"  async defer></script>
```